# I have a pipe separated file,read file row wise and search for unclosed quotes(") in each row and close that

Tags: text-processing, quoting, csv

Below is a row and i need to close "20 with "20"

```
2019-02-15T10:25:19+0100|ttt|werewrw|erewr|fddsfsdf|dfsdf|07|2ee7|1b65d04|"20|19|-02-|15t10:03|45435435|765767||SIP;rr=200;text="hyt"|
```

Comment: Is it _always_ `"20` or could it be `"any-number` or `"any-text`? Is it only one on a row, or can there be many of these instances?

Comment: it is always like this |"20| in only one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this as a test file:

```
$ cat text
start|10|"20|end
"10"|"20|"30"|end
"20|"10|"30|end
abc|def|"20"|30|"end
```

To close all open `"`, try:

```
$ sed -E 's/^("[^"|]*)\|/\1"|/; :a; s/(\|"[^"|]*)\|/\1"|/g; ta; s/\|"[^"|]*$/&"/' text
start|10|"20"|end
"10"|"20"|"30"|end
"20"|"10"|"30"|end
abc|def|"20"|30|"end"
```

#### How it works

If the unclosed quote can occur in the first field, a middle field or the end field, then there are three cases to consider.  Thus, we have three substitute commands:

- `s/^("[^"|]*)\|/\1"|/`

  If the line begins with a quote but no quote appears before the first `|`, this adds the quote.
- `:a; s/(\|"[^"|]*)\|/\1"|/g; ta;`

  If a quote is missing in a middle field, this adds it.  To make sure that all such missing quotes are added, the substitute command is repeated until no more changes are made.
- `s/\|"[^"|]*$/&"/`

  If the final field is missing a closing quote, then it is added.